# Trouble with Setting defaultValue/value in Material-UI Autocomplete Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm encountering an issue with setting the defaultValue or value in a Material-UI Autocomplete component. The goal is to programmatically set the default value based on certain conditions, but it doesn't seem to reflect in the UI. Its also occured to me that if the component renders before the value is there, defaultValue would not work. So I did try the same with value rather than defaultValue.

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
<Autocomplete
  options={[{ value: true, label: FILTERS_ENUM.CHANGED }, { value: false, label: FILTERS_ENUM.UNCHANGED }]}
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField
      size='small'
      placeholder='Changed & Unchanged'
      {...params}
    />
  )}
  PaperComponent={CustomPaper}
  onChange={(e, value) => {
    doFilter(value, FILTERS_ENUM.CHANGED)
  }}
  //does not work
  {...(
    filters[FILTERS_ENUM.CHANGED] === null ? null :
    filters[FILTERS_ENUM.CHANGED] && filters[FILTERS_ENUM.CHANGED].value
      ? { defaultValue: { value: true, label: FILTERS_ENUM.CHANGED } }
      : { defaultValue: { value: false, label: FILTERS_ENUM.UNCHANGED }}
  )}
  //does work
  defaultValue={{ value: false, label: FILTERS_ENUM.UNCHANGED }}
/>
```

The expected behavior is that the Autocomplete should display the label from FILTERS_ENUM based on the condition provided in the ternary operation. However, it always defaults to { value: false, label: FILTERS_ENUM.UNCHANGED }, regardless of the condition.

I have tried using both defaultValue and value props, but neither seems to work as expected. The onChange event works fine and updates the state correctly, but the initial value does not reflect the state.

Has anyone faced a similar issue or can spot what I might be doing wrong here? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: how is `filters` being set? if this is value `x` on the first render this will be your default value, not matter how you change it in subsequent renders